# Getting text from grid colum while doing horizontal scrolling

Tags: automation, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

There is an angular grid and it has 25 columns. Now only 5 columns are visible on the page and to make other columns visible, I have to do horizontal scroll.

I want the text of all the column headers as grid keeps on scrolling horizontally across. any help from protractor experts?

This question has been asked many times but no solution yet.

Wrote below code but it is giving me the text of visible columns only.

```
    var gridclass= $('.ui-grid-viewport');
    var columnheader= $('.ui-grid-columns);
    browser.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).scrollLeft(arguments[0].scrollLeft + 20)",gridclass.getWebElement());
    columnheader.getText();
```

Expected: I should get the text of all the columns as grid keep on scrolling
Actual: I am getting the text of only visible columns on the page

Comment: Does your code scroll at all?

Comment: yup, it works but scrolls to some extent, no completely. I was wondering if there is such thing like it will scroll in one time go and get the text of columns while scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.ui-grid-columns` identifies the table row containing the all the column headers can you try using the inner text attribute like so

```
var columnheaders= $('.ui-grid-columns');
columnheaders.getAttribute('innerText')
```

Comment: What does `.ui-grid-columns` identify?

Comment: It is a class of column header. When I used your code then It gave me text of only visible columns on the page

Answer (score 0):

Use getAttribute("textContent") instead of getText().

Comment: Thanks. I will try

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to DOM not render the whole page completely. You could try to set the resolution of browser bigger like 3840 x 2160, then getText() all column headers.